# "subscribeToMore" Apollo Client Subscriptions behaving weirdly

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm creating a pannel for live discussion where I've used susbcribeToMore inside of useEffect. The same logic I also used in a chaat companent where it is working as expected unlike here. Here's my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = subscribeToMore({
      document: DISCUSSION_SUBSCRIPTION,
      variables: { authUserId: props.userId, groupId: props.groupId },
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
        if (!subscriptionData) return prev;
        const newDiscussion = subscriptionData.data.DiscussionCreated;
        console.log(newDiscussion);
        console.log(prev);
        const mergedDiscussion = [...prev.getDiscussions, newDiscussion];

        console.log(mergedDiscussion);
        return { getDiscussions: mergedDiscussion };
      },
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [props.groupId, props.userId, subscribeToMore]);
```

When sender X sends a discussion message to sender Y, sender X can see his UI update with the new message. In sender Y's console I am able to see newDiscussion and prev due to the console log but the UI for Sender Y does not update. This is true however for only the first message. When sender X sends another message the console log of 'prev' shows undefined. And I also get this error:

````
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDiscussions' of undefined
    at updateQuery (NewDiscussionPanel.js:126)
    at bundle.esm.js:337
    at bundle.esm.js:409
    at tryFunctionOrLogError (bundle.esm.js:931)
    at ObservableQuery.updateQuery (bundle.esm.js:408)
    at Object.next (bundle.esm.js:335)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:151)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:195)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (Observable.js:247)
    at Object.next (Observable.js:337)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:151)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:195)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (Observable.js:247)
    at bundle.esm.js:1086
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.next (bundle.esm.js:1085)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:151)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:195)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (Observable.js:247)
    at Object.next (bundle.esm.js:32)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:151)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:195)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (Observable.js:247)
    at Object.handler (client.js:298)
    at SubscriptionClient.processReceivedData (client.js:755)
    at WebSocket.client.onmessage (client.js:701)```
````

So obviously the UI for user Y still doesn't update after the second message too. It still updates for the user X. The backend has been tested and is working fine so this is definitely an error on the frontend. It'd be great if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: The reason that user X can see the messages is probably caue once they send the message the UI updates which causes re-render. If I refresh the page then both the users can see all messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Object.assign({}, prev, { getDiscussions: mergedDiscussion })` instead of `{ getDiscussions: mergedDiscussion }`.